# UIImageView contentMode different in retina and non-retina dispaly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

So I have this `UIImageView` with an image on top of it. When I'm using normal iPhone display, it shows inside the `UIImageView` exactly as it supposed to - in the `UIImageView` bounds, the problem is when I'm using retina display device, the image becomes big and doesn't fit the `UIImageView` bounds, it goes all over the screen.

How can I fix this issue? I want the image in Retina display to fit inside the `UIImageView` size.

This is my code:

```
- (UIImage *)loadScreenShotImageFromDocumentsDirectory
{
    UIImage * tempimage;
    NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
    NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MeasureScreenShot.png", docDirectory];
    tempimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    return tempimage;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Setting the image
    UIImage * Image = [self loadScreenShotImageFromDocumentsDirectory];
    theImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 166, 290, 334);
    theImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;        
    theImageView.image = Image;
}
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 0):

When I was using an image with core plot, I had to scale the image for the retina display.

```
 CPTImage *fillimage = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:bubble.CGImage scale:bubble.scale];
```

the name of the image file was bubble and I had a bubble file and a bubble@2x file.  This let the image fit the image view for either display.  Hope this helps.